# Select with Field

Tags: custom-fields, channel-fields, ee5

I have a Select Dropdown field named Type belonging to a Channel.
Inside I created a Value / Label menu.

**I would like to print the values ​​in a Select in front-end.**

**Below I put my code that does NOT work.**

**From the documentation it seems to me that my code is correct.**
**I forgot something?**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Tipologia</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="tipologia">
        <option>Tutti i comuni</option>
        {field_name}
        <option value="{field_name}">{field_name}</option>
        {/field_name}
    </select>
</div>
```

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using this inside a channel entry loop, correct? If not, you need to be.

And you might also try using the other field segements:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="my_channel_with_select_field"
    limit="1"
    dynamic="no"
    entry_id="the_entry_id_of_the_entry_i_want_to_output"}

    {select_field_name}
    Field value : {select_field_name:value} <br/>
    Field label : {select_field_name:label}
    {/select_field_name}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Just to make sure you aren't confused, this will output the selected value for a specific entry in that channel. If you are looking to output multiple values selected for an entry, you need to use a Multiselect Dropdown, not a regular select. And lastly, if you are looking to output this in a form, and you want to output all options the field has regardless of any entry in the channel, you need to use the channel form tag to do so:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html#other-channel-fields

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick reply.

I'm not inside a channel. I just want to generate a Select HTML with the values ​​that contains my custom field.

Just as written in the documentation at the link below.

Link: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/select.html

The custom field is the same as that written in the documentation.
I want to print all the Value contained in the custom field.

Comment: Field types and field definitions simply define what you can store in a channel - they don't store any data themselves.  So if you have defined your custom field, the only way to have it populate a form is to store some values in a channel entry and then recall it as @jrothafer notes.  If you just want to pre-define the content of the select / option field, a better bet would be to store the values you want in a `template partial` and recall it in similar fashion to how you show it in your example.  More here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/design/template_partials/index.html